# asp:button with no post back or refreshing the page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have button in my page that when click on fires a jquery method that shows a div, but if the browser doesn't support javascript I want to fire a code behind method (using a postback).  Is this possible?  I'm already using this code but i can't see any results:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload Files Here" Width="187px" onClick="CodeBehindMethod" OnClientClick="show_upload_box();return false"/>
```

and this is my jquery code:

```
function show_upload_box() {
    $("#pop_up_background").css({
        "opacity": "0.4"
    });
    $("#pop_up_background").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#signup_pop_up_box").fadeIn('slow');
    window.scroll(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: @freefaller that's not the problem it was just typing mistake

Comment: What do you mean "you can't see any results"? Your code should work as expected. OnClientClick should stop the post back.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev : well it doesn't work , it refreshes the page

Comment: I can't replicate in any browser. Using the code you provided, there is no post back.

Comment: By any browser I mean Firefox, Safari (windows), Chrome, IE 9. Perhaps try simply `OnClientClick="return show_upload_box()"` and put the `return false;` on last line of the function.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev That did the work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the browser doesn't support JavaScript then your button would not work.

In ASP.NET, the runat="server" instruction is actually tied to a JavaScript method that submits a form (view page source to see that method).

Change or remove the value of that property to prevent the post back to your server.